# Execute series of Stored procedures in Databricks using Scala

Tags: sql-server, azure, scala, stored-procedures, azure-databricks

I am working in a migration project, where lift and shift method is used to migrate SQL server DB from onprem to AZure Cloud. There is a lot of stored procedures used for integration in On prem.Now here in On prem , to process the XMl file and execute the same procedures pointing to the cloud Db I need to write a code in Databricks. I have code to execute a single stored procedure using Scala, as I am new to coding in python/scala I couldn't find the right method to execute the procedures.

The below code is what I have used to execute one procedure- sample

```
%scala

val username = "xxxxx"
val pass = "xxxxx"
val url = "jdbc:sqlserver://xxx.database.windows.net:1433;databaseName=xxx"
val table = "SalesLT.Temp3"
val query = s"EXEC sp_truncate_table '${table}'"


val conn = DriverManager.getConnection(url, username, pass)
val rs = conn.createStatement.execute(query)
```

I have a requirement to execute some 10 stored procedures in series.
Looking forward for your suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

To run multiple stored procedures sequentially you can **create one Stored procedure and call all your stored procedures in that** and call this stored procedure through Databricks.

The following code example is referred from [here](https://www.sqlservercentral.com/forums/topic/execute-stored-procedure-sequentially) by **@Thom A**

```sql
CREATE PROC MySP1  @int  int AS  
     PRINT @int  /  0;  --To error  
GO  
  
CREATE PROC MySP2  @int  int AS   
     PRINT @int  +  1;  
GO  
  
CREATE PROC MySP3  @int  int AS  
     PRINT @int  +  2;  
GO  
  
CREATE PROC AllMySPs  @Int  int AS  
     PRINT 'Executing SP1...';  
     BEGIN TRY  
         EXEC MySP1  @Int;  
     END TRY  
     BEGIN CATCH  
         PRINT 'MySP1 failed';  
     END CATCH  
     PRINT 'Executing SP2...';  
     BEGIN TRY  
         EXEC MySP2  @Int;  
     END TRY  
     BEGIN CATCH  
         PRINT 'MySP2 failed';  
     END CATCH  
     PRINT 'Executing SP3...';  
     BEGIN TRY  
         EXEC MySP3  @Int;  
     END TRY  
     BEGIN CATCH  
         PRINT 'MySP3 failed';  
     END CATCH  
GO
```